# Non Wordpress Folder in a Wordpress Site

Tags: htaccess

On localhost (WAMP server) I have installed wordpress in the root directory (examplesite.com).  I have an application that needs to run outside of Wordpress, so I would like it in the folder /application (examplesite.com/application).   I created the folder “application” in the root, but when I go to the url examplesite.com/application, I get the message “Forbidden you don't have permission to access examplesite/application/< on this server”.

I found a solution suggesting to add the following to my htaccess, but it didn’t work for me.

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/application/(.*)$ [OR]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
    </IfModule>
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress`
```

Any advice?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You can revert to the default WordPress rewrite rules. This line already handles checking for existing physical directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Your problem does not lie with WordPress, but with some other problem with your server/htaccess files. You have not provided enough information to solve your problem, but it probably is an issue with file permissions, `Deny from` rules in htaccess, or indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like that:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/application/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and additional .htaccess in application folder